# Accessing a variable which is registered for another host

Tags: ansible

The situation is I have registered a variable in one playbook which is primarily run in host1 (e.g.) and the IP is registered for host2

```
- name: Reading vdu-GUI IPs and storing them in variables
  hosts: host2
  remote_user: root
  tasks:
    - debug: var=ansible_all_ipv4_addresses
      register: host2_ip
    - debug: var=host2_ip
```

Now I am trying to exchange key from host3 to host2:

```
- name: Exchange Keys between servers
  hosts: host3
  remote_user: root
  tasks:
   - name: Check for presence of key
     stat:
       path: ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
     register: keyStat

- name: Create key on ControlServer if it does not exist already
  shell: "ssh-keygen -t rsa -b 2048 -f ~/.ssh/id_rsa -N '' -q"
  when: keyStat.stat.exists != True

- name: Copy the file from master to the destination vms
  shell: "sshpass -p Passw0rd ssh-copy-id -i /root/.ssh/id_rsa -o 'StrictHostKeyChecking=no' root@{{ host2_ip }}"
```

This gives me undefined variable error:

```
TASK [Copy the file from master to the destination vms] task path: 
/tmp/ansible-execution-6RtsPw/playbook/ansible/test.yml:213
fatal: [8c0b69ef-dae2-4ebf-8b5a-2c522b677a31]: FAILED! => {
"failed": true,
"msg": "the field 'args' has an invalid value, which appears to include 
a variable that is undefined. The error was: 'host2_ip_addr' is 
undefined\n\nThe error appears to have been in '/tmp/ansible-execution- 
6RtsPw/playbook/ansible/test.yml': line 213, column 6, but may\nbe 
elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.\n\nThe 
offending line appears to be:\n\n\n   - name: Copy the file from master 
to the destination vms\n     ^ here\n"
}
```

Comment: The question is not consistent. "The error was: host2_ip_addr is 
undefined", but there is no "host2_ip_addr" in the code.

Comment: To generate ssh key use *generate_ssh_key* parameter of [user](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/user_module.html#user-manage-user-accounts). To transfer public keys use [authorized_key](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/authorized_key_module.html#authorized-key-adds-or-removes-an-ssh-authorized-key).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[hostvars](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_variables.html#accessing-information-about-other-hosts-with-magic-variables) can be used to

> access variables for another host, including facts that have been gathered about that host. You can access host variables at any point in a playbook...

For example the playbook below

```
- hosts: test_02
  gather_facts: yes
  tasks:
    - debug:
        var: ansible_all_ipv4_addresses

- hosts: test_03
  gather_facts: yes
  tasks:
    - debug:
        var: hostvars['test_02'].ansible_all_ipv4_addresses
```

gives (abridged):

```
PLAY [test_02]
TASK [debug]
ok: [test_02] => {
"ansible_all_ipv4_addresses": [
    "10.1.0.52"
    ]
}
PLAY [test_03]
TASK [debug]
ok: [test_03] => {
"hostvars['test_02'].ansible_all_ipv4_addresses": [
    "10.1.0.52"
    ]
 }
```